# Get text from all <a> tags in string

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing, text-extraction

Since I am completely useless at regex and this has been bugging me for the past half an hour, I think I'll post this up here as it's probably quite simple.

```
<a href="/folder/files/hey/">hey.exe</a>
<a href="/folder/files/hey2/">hey2.dll</a>
<a href="/folder/files/pomp/">pomp.jpg</a>
```

In PHP I need to extract what's between the `<a>` tags example:

```
hey.exe
hey2.dll
pomp.jpg
```

Comment: Related: [Find the text inside <a> and </a> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4414427/2943403)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid using '.*' even if you make it ungreedy, until you have some more practice with RegEx.  I think a good solution for you would be:

```
'/<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/i'
```

Note the '/' delimiters - you must use the preg suite of regex functions in PHP.  It would look like this:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
// matches get stored in '$matches' variable as an array
// matches in between the <a></a> tags will be in $matches[1]
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: +1 for recommending against (.*) and using exclusive character classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

`<a href="[^"]*">([^<]*)</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple one:

```
<a.*>(.*)</a>
```

However, you should be careful if you have several matches in the same line, e.g.

```
<a href="/folder/hey">hey.exe</a><a href="/folder/hey2/">hey2.dll</a>
```

In this case, the correct regex would be:

```
<a.*?>(.*?)</a>
```

Note the '?' after the '*' quantifier. By default, quantifiers are greedy, which means they eat as much characters as they can (meaning they would return only "hey2.dll" in this example). By appending a quotation mark, you make them ungreedy, which should better fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work:

```
$pattern = '/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/';
```