# Find the text inside <a> and </a> tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need a very little help to find the content inside certain  and  tags.

Example:

```
$string = '<a href="dummyurl">TEXT</a><span>Other Text</span>';
```

I'd like to find 'TEXT' and replace it with some other value. Obviuosly the content of 'href' and 'TEXT' is dynamically generated.

Comment: Are you dealing only with HTML snippets or whole HTML documents?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure there's no `>` character in the  start tag (except for the obvious 1):

```
preg_match('/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<a href="dummyurl">TEXT</a><span>Other Text</span>');
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$len = $anchors->length;
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if($anchors->item($i)->nodeValue == 'foo') {
        $anchors->item($i)->nodeValue = 'New Value';
        $anchors->item($i)->setAttribute('href', 'new href');
    }
}
$newHTML = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $newHTML;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Who's talking about DOM? He has a string $string, not a DOM.

Comment: ...and that string can be used to create a 'micro-dom' from which attributes can easily be extracted from elements, and modified, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Consider learning the DOM, which will enable you to work with both HTML and XML documents and answer questions like this in a generic manner.  There is some learning curve, and it will be slower than fine-tuned local regexes, but it'll be more robust as well as applicable to nearly everything that is an HTML or XML document.

PHP has a whole big section on using the DOM in PHP [within the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: Who's talking about DOM? He has a string $string, not a DOM.

Comment: actual code would have helped avoid confusion; but the link is PHP info

Comment: This broad hint could have been a comment under the question.