# PHP How to div tags and retain a href?

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$str= <<<EOT
<div class="tb">
<div class="mg"><a href="/File/13970909.jpg" class="in" title="En"></a></div>
Title1 <a href="/File/name1" title="name1">title2</a> introduce.</div>
</div>
EOT;
```

PHP How to div tags and retain a href? It can not use easy `strip_tags`

I need something back:

```
<a href="/File/13970909.jpg">title1</a>
Title2<a href="/File/name1">title3</a> introduce.
```

Comment: Why can you not use `strip_tags()`? It has an option for keeping selected tags.

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "How to div tags and retain a href?"

Comment: @Evan Teran I think what he's trying to say is that he wants to strip the `<div>` tags while leaving the `<a>` tags

Comment: Your expected output clearly doesn't match the input. `title1` jumps from being outside both the `<div>` and `<a>` to within the `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks All, I want remove all the `tags`, and their `attributes`, just retain `text` and `href` value, like `<a href="/File/13970909.jpg">title1</a>
Title2<a href="/File/name1">title3</a> introduce.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strip_tags()`, allowing the `<a>` tag to remain:

```
$str= <<<EOT
<div class="tb">
<div class="mg"><a href="/File/13970909.jpg" class="in" title="En"></a></div>
Title1 <a href="/File/name1" title="name1">title2</a> introduce.</div>
</div>
EOT;

// Strip out all tags except <a>
echo strip_tags($str, "<a>");
```

Comment: so how to remove all the `attributes` in `a`, just retain `href`?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the exact output you are looking for...

```
$str = strip_tags($str, '<a>');
```

The strip_tags() function allows you to pass in a list of allowed tags. So you allow the tags you want and voila!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: thanks, and how to remove `all the attributes` in `a`, just retain `href`? thanks.

Comment: Let me think on that a bit. On initial thought I would say that you would probably need to extract the href contents then replace the opening anchor tag with your custom opening that inserts the extracted href. Why do you want this anyways?

Comment: You could probably loop through the attributes using a DomDocument object. Here are some posts about that... http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?p=10977958 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414427/find-the-text-inside-a-and-a-tags or you could get really complex with it and use php jquery so that you can go through it in php like you would with JQuery http://jquery.hohli.com/.